# A mathematically strange rebus

Tags: mathematics, rebus

*What does the following [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus) represent?*

$\lfloor cards \rfloor $ $+$ $\lceil cards \rceil $

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It represents

> House of Cards

because

> The brackets represent the *floor* and *ceiling* functions, respectively. Put these components together, and you can make a house.

Comment: Wow, that was just way too fast.I can't even accept your answer right now.

Comment: I had the floor and ceiling but I didn't get to *that*

Comment: It'd be pretty dangerous unless you also add some walls...

Comment: if math had a wall function, we'd probably have see it here

Comment: The absolute value function looks like a pair of walls.

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> Omaha HI-LO
>  Because you're putting together the ceiling and floor of cards.